# Ariana Grande verse in key of D, track is still in C: Save your tears remix

Tags: recording, singers

In this video:
[The Weeknd & Ariana Grande - Save Your Tears (Remix)](https://youtu.be/d7dDFcTmZP8)

Ariana Grande sings in the key of D while the backing track stays in the original key of C.

Did she manage to do that while listening to the musical accompaniment in its original tune, or did she record it in a different session, with her part being then mixed with the rest of this number ?

Comment: https://youtu.be/d7dDFcTmZP8?t=98 just looks plain wrong. Someone must have forgotten to switch the auto-tune on.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is the official video for "The Weeknd & Ariana Grande - Save Your Tears (Remix)".](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LIIDh-qI9oI)  The video you linked is not the official video, and Ariana Grande doesn't even sing on that version.  The channel which uploaded it is full of mislabeled videos which cut off halfway through.  Very strange, perhaps they are farming clicks for ad revenue?

Anyway, here's the most likely way we arrived at this recording:  The vocal track was recorded by the singer while listening to the backing track, and she sang it in the right key.  Then a producer either a) tuned the vocals to the wrong key, or b) changed the key of the backing track *after* recording.  Now the backing track and vocals are in different keys and it sounds <strike>terrible</strike> polytonal.